# How to read every 100 lines from a large file

Tags: bash

How do I read every 100 lines in a larger file of around 100000 lines. I want to read every 100 lines in one iteration and make them coma seperated, run some code and next iteration, it should pick from 101 to 200.

I have searched internet, everywhere there is a solution for picking nth line and not n lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapfile` and specify count. Remember to check the end condition, as `mapfile` doesn't set it's return status to nonzero on EOF condition.

```
# read 100 lines
while while mapfile -t -n2 lines && ((${#lines[@]})); do
     # output the lines separated with comma
     ( IFS=','; echo "${lines[*]}"; )
     # run some code
     : run some code
done < larger_file
```

Comment: Just a small correction, I want them' OR ' separated, but not able to do with IFS.

Comment: Got it, was able to do with this echo "${lines[*]}" | sed "s/ /& OR /g"